# Node.js - exec command for tar files works correctly first time, but produces corrupted tar contents upon subsequent execution

Tags: node.js, linux, tar

I am building a web app with Node.js, and I am at a point where I need to produce a tar archive of a directory of PDFs. The application is running on a VM running Ubuntu 14.04 server. My code to do this is shown below:

```
function tarDirectory(path, token, callback) {
  var exec = require('child_process').exec;
  var cmd = 'cd ' + path + ' && tar -cvf genericName-' + token + '.tar' + ' ' + token;

  exec(cmd, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log(stdout);
    console.log(stderr);
    if (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
    if(callback) callback();
  });
}
```

and this tarDirectory function is called by the following code:

```
router.post('/files/generate', function(req, res, next) {
  IDList = req.body['IDs[]'];
  token = req.body['token'];

  // if just a single file being generated
  if (typeof req.body['IDs[]'] === "string"){
      filehelper.generateFile(IDList[0], req.app.locals.site.basedir + "temp/", token);
  }
  // if multiple files being generated
  else {
    IDList.forEach(function(id) {
      filehelper.generateFile(id, req.app.locals.site.basedir + "temp/", token);
    });
  }
  filehelper.tarDirectory(req.app.locals.site.basedir + "temp/", token, res.end);
});
```

The code expects a post request with dynamic data that is generated by a button click in my web app, and will then create files based on the data and tar it into a directory. This all works fine and good... the first time. When I click the button for the first time in a while, the tar is produced, and when I open it, the client-side PDFs are identical to the ones on the server. When I click again within an hour or so, though, I receive a tar file, but when I open the archive and unpack it, the PDFs are all corrupted and about half the expected byte size. I am at a loss here... I had a suspicion that it might be related to improper handling of stream closing, but I'm not sure.

This is the code that generates the PDFs into a directory, which is then tarred after the generation:

```
function generateFile(id, path, token) {
  var dirPath = path + token;
  var filePath = path + token + "/file" + id + ".pdf";

  console.log("creating file for: " + id);

  try{
    fs.statSync(dirPath).isDirectory();
  } catch (err) {
    fs.mkdirSync(dirPath);
  }
  // start the file pdf generation
  file = new PDFDocument();
  output = fs.createWriteStream(filePath);
  output.on('close', function(){
    return;
  });

  file.pipe(output);

  // handle the intricacies of the file generation
  file.text("file" + id + ".pdf");

  // end the file
  file.end();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Is everything okay with pdf files, before compressing?
2. In your `generateFile` function you have WriteStream, which is async. But, you calling this function as sync., and start .tar compression without waiting before pdf generation be complete, which may cause this issue.
3. As recommendation: try to wrap `generateFile` with promise, or iterate async., and start compression only after all files generation completed.

Example with bluebird:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');

function generateFile(id, path, token) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  var dirPath = path + token;
  var filePath = path + token + "/file" + id + ".pdf";

  console.log("creating file for: " + id);

  try{
    fs.statSync(dirPath).isDirectory();
  } catch (err) {
    fs.mkdirSync(dirPath);
  }
  // start the file pdf generation
  file = new PDFDocument();
  output = fs.createWriteStream(filePath);
  output.on('close', function(){
    return resolve();
  });

  output.on('error', function(error) {
    return reject(error);
  });

  file.pipe(output);

  // handle the intricacies of the file generation
  file.text("file" + id + ".pdf");

  // end the file
  file.end();
  });
}
```

Pdfs generation and compressing.

```
 var Promise = require('bluebird');

    ....

    //IDList.forEach(function(id) {
    //      filehelper.generateFile(id, req.app.locals.site.basedir + "temp/", //token);});

    //replace with

    Promise.map(IDList, function(id) {
      return filehelper.generateFile(id, req.app.locals.site.basedir + "temp/", token);
    })
    .then(function() {
    //all files are ready, start compressing
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
    //we have error
    });
```

Comment: 1. Yes, the PDFs are intact in their original folders on the server, so they are definitely being generated correctly.
2. I think that this is on the right track... I will look into using promises for this.
3. Thank you for the example :)

Comment: So after implementing your suggestion of promises, I was able to get it to a point where it generates the PDFs properly if it is only generating one at a time. Investigating... will get back to you

Answer (score 0):

So I implemented the promises that Nazar suggested. The total operation now works mostly fine if I am generating just one file, but if I generate more I get the same corrupt PDFs.

My code to generate the individual files:

```
function generateFile(id, path, token) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    var dirPath = path + token;
    var filePath = path + token + "/file" + id + ".pdf";

    console.log("creating file for: " + id);

    try{
      fs.statSync(dirPath).isDirectory();
    } catch (err) {
      fs.mkdirSync(dirPath);
    }
    // start the file pdf generation
    file = new PDFDocument();
    output = fs.createWriteStream(filePath);

    // stream handling
    output.on('finish', function(){
      console.log(fs.statSync(filePath)["size"]);
      return resolve();
    });

    output.on('error', function(error) {
      return reject(error);
    });

    // pipe the generated PDF to the output file
    file.pipe(output);

    // handle the intricacies of the transcript generation
    file.text("file" + id + ".pdf");

    // end the file
    file.end();
  });
}
```

My code to tar the directory:

```
function tarDirectory(path, token) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    var exec = require('child_process').exec;
    var cmd = 'cd ' + path + ' && tar -cvf Files-' + token + '.tar' + ' ' + token;

    exec(cmd, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
      if (stdout != "") console.log(stdout);
      if (stderr != "") console.log(stderr);
      if (error) return reject(error);
      return resolve();
    });
  });
}
```

and my code that calls the two helper functions:

```
// submit request to generate files
router.post('/files/generate', function(req, res, next) {
  IDList = req.body['IDs[]'];
  token = req.body['token'];

  // convert single fileID into list because Promise.map() needs iterable
  if (typeof IDList === "string") {
    IDList = [IDList];
  }

  Promise.map(IDList, function(id) {
    filehelper.generateFile(id, req.app.locals.site.basedir + "temp/", token);
  })
  .then(function() {
    return filehelper.tarDirectory(req.app.locals.site.basedir + "temp/", token);
  })
  .then(function() {
    res.end();
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    throw new Error('Something went wrong while generating the tar file! :(\n' + error);
  });
});
```

Any further insights as to what I could be doing wrong here are much appreciated.

Comment: do the next: `function generateFile`, replace `resolve()` with `resolve({id:id, path: filePath})`.
and in `Promise.map` - first `.then(function()` with `then(function(files)`. 
Print this files, to verify that names are correct. There are not enough info. And my thought that you trying to write to the same file.

Comment: I solved the problem. It stemmed from the fact that I was not returning the promise generated in Promise.map(). Cheers for all your help Nazar.